# What can be wrong in converting grayscale image from PIL to QPixmap?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, python-imaging-library, qpixmap

My program opens famous [Lena](http://www.google.pl/search?hl=pl&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=775&q=lena&oq=lena&gs_l=img.12...0.0.1.32684.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1ac..5.img.Az3FN5oY3XU#hl=pl&site=imghp&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=lena%20grayscale&oq=lena%20grayscale&gs_l=img.12...0.0.0.4284.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c..5.img.sAzrLcVQ7Ck&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=50df47ad21472006&biw=1600&bih=775) image, then converts it to PIL image and then converts it to QPixmap.

```
import sys
import cStringIO

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PIL import Image

class ImageLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QLabel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')
        im = Image.open('Test_Images/Lena.bmp')

        self.bufor=QtCore.QBuffer()
        self.bufor.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        im.save(self.bufor, "PNG")

        strio = cStringIO.StringIO()
        strio.write(self.bufor.data())
        self.bufor.close()
        strio.seek(0)
        self.pil_image = Image.open(strio)
        self.pil_image.save('pil_image.png', 'PNG')
        data = self.pil_image.tostring()

        image = QtGui.QImage(data, self.pil_image.size[0], self.pil_image.size[1], QtGui.QImage.Format_Indexed8)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.setPixmap(pix)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
imageLabel = ImageLabel()
imageLabel.show()
```

But I get tilted and multiplied image [Lena after transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPwor.png)

What is strange: programs works correctly with some similar (grayscale, 8BPP) images.
What can be wrong?

Comment: How can my question be a duplicate as it was asked 3 years before the second question?